# 2 files containing some same strings

Tags: regex, linux, text, awk, grep

I have 2 files....

FILE1:

```
012:coffee
013:salt
014:apple
015:mushrooms
016:tree
```

FILE2:

```
Subject: Three tips to get the most out of Gmail
Subject: The best of Gmail, wherever you are
Subject: Stay more organized with Gmail's inbox
Subject: 012
Subject: 014
```

How can I generate a new file that will compare the previous two and contain:

```
012:coffee
014:apple
```

Comment: Question is not completely clear. On what basis you are trying to get the output? Please update the question with more details

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With single **`awk`** command:

```
awk -F':[[:space:]]*' 'NR==FNR{ if($2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) a[$2]; next }$1 in a' file2 file1
```

The output:

```
012:coffee
014:apple
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk -F':' '
NR==FNR {
    sub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"")
    a[$0]
    next
}
$1 in a
' file2 file1
```

You need the sub() approach instead of relying on $2 in case the subject text in file2 contains colons.